# How to traverse the enums in any given set?

Tags: delphi, enums, set

I have a whole lot of enum types which are coupled with a corresponding set, such as...

```
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
  TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum;
```

I'm trying to come up with a single set of functions which can work on *any* enum set, rather than writing separate functions for each and every one. These functions will be responsible for interpreting the values which are included in a given set.

For a single specific set, I may have a function like this...

```
var
  E: TMyEnum;
begin
  for E := Low(TMyEnum) to High(TMyEnum) do begin
    if E in SomeGivenSet then
      CheckListBox.Checked[Integer(E)]:= True;
  end;
end;
```

...and...

```
var
  E: TMyEnum;
begin
  for E := Low(TMyEnum) to High(TMyEnum) do begin
    if CheckListBox.Checked[Integer(E)] then
      SomeGivenSet:= SomeGivenSet + [E];
  end;
end;
```

How do I accomplish the above to be re-usable for *any* given enum/set type?

Example usage:

```
procedure LoadEnums(AEnumType: TAnyEnumType; ASet: TAnySet; AList: TCheckListBox);
procedure SaveEnums(AEnumType: TAnyEnumType; ASet: TAnySet; AList: TCheckListBox);

LoadEnums(TMyEnum, MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
SaveEnums(TMyEnum, MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899327/2039575) and interpreting the set as a bitfield is a possible solution

Comment: Have you tried using generics?

Comment: @ub_coding Getting the type info isn't the problem. It's the *values assigned to a set* which I need help with.

Comment: @DelphiCoder No, otherwise I probably wouldn't need to ask a question :-)

Comment: @JerryDodge See [Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Generics_Index) in Embarcadero's documentation.  This is pretty easy to solve using a Generic parameter for the enum type, and RTTI to access the enum's defined values.  Provided the enum values start at 0 and are sequential, otherwise no RTTI will be generated for the enum.

Comment: A combination of generics and RTTI is indeed how I handle this sort of thing. I'm pretty sure that the spring4d project contains some code in this vein that would prove instructive.

Comment: @Remy I'm well aware of what generics are, I just have no clue how to use it to solve this.

Comment: https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/27397

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330090/11329562

Comment: I once used these two sources to add some enum “helper“ to my toolbox. Maybe the InRange functionality is what you are looking for...

Comment: The challenge is not necessarily the enums themselves - it's the *set* of an enum type (`TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum;`). I have no problem with a single enum. I can cast it as *integer* if I want and back, and get its string value, etc. What I need help with is the *set*, most importantly, passing such a set as a parameter to a function. None of the proposed solutions / links here seem to have anything to do with sets...

Comment: @JerryDodge You can use Generics to accept a specific value of an enum type, and a `Set` of that enum type, as function input parameters, and then use RTTI to determine the min/max values of the enum type, and then loop between those values testing the `Set` for each value. I guess I'll just have to write it up for you...

Comment: @Remy Thanks, Generics and RTTI are like Greek and French to me - only thing I've ever used from either is a `TList<>` :-)

Comment: I don't think you are going to get a type safe solution here, because of the limitation of Delphi generic constraints. Perhaps the closes you will get is to parameterise on both enum and set type, and then use a runtime check, e.g. an assertion, that the set type is indeed a set of the specified enum. The problem I have with your bounty is that I don't think your scope is sufficiently honed. I can imagine spending time working up something, only for the scope to change. Also, if the code in Remy's answer does not compile, you can fix it. You have enough skill to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using a mix of Generics and RTTI to do what you are looking for, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., CheckLst, TypInfo;

type
  TEnumSerialize<EnumType: record> = class
  private
    class function GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
  public
    type SetType = Set of EnumType;
    class procedure LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
    class procedure SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
  end;

class function TEnumSerialize<EnumType>.GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
var
  TI: PTypeInfo;
begin
  TI := TypeInfo(EnumType);
  if Assigned(TI) and (TI^.Kind = tkEnumeration) then
    Result := GetTypeData(TI)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<EnumType>.LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  AList.CheckAll(cbUnchecked);

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if EnumType(Value) in ASet then
      AList.Checked[Value] := True;
  end;
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<EnumType>.SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  VSet := [];

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if AList.Checked[Value] then
      Include(VSet, EnumType(Value));
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
  TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum;

var
  MyEnums: TMyEnums;

// initialize MyEnums as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnum>.LoadEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// use lstMyEnumCheckList as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnum>.SaveEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// save MyEnums as needed...
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
uses
  ..., CheckLst, TypInfo;

type
  TEnumSerialize<SetType> = class
  private
    class function GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
  public
    class procedure LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
    class procedure SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
  end;

class function TEnumSerialize<SetType>.GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
var
  TI: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Result := nil;

  TI := TypeInfo(SetType);
  if not (Assigned(TI) and (TI^.Kind = tkSet)) then Exit;

  TD := GetTypeData(TI);
  if not (Assigned(TD^.CompType) and (TD^.CompType^.Kind = tkEnumeration)) then Exit;

  Result := GetTypeData(TD^.CompType^);
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<SetType>.LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  AList.CheckAll(cbUnchecked);

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if Value in ASet then
      AList.Checked[Value] := True;
  end;
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<SetType>.SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  VSet := [];

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if AList.Checked[Value] then
      Include(VSet, Value);
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
  TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum;

var
  MyEnums: TMyEnums;

// initialize MyEnums as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnums>.LoadEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// use lstMyEnumCheckList as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnums>.SaveEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// save MyEnums as needed...
```

If that doesn't work, you will likely have to include both enum and set types in the Generic parameters, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., CheckLst, TypInfo;

type
  TEnumSerialize<EnumType, SetType> = class
  private
    class function GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
  public
    class procedure LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
    class procedure SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
  end;

class function TEnumSerialize<EnumType, SetType>.GetEnumTypeData: PTypeData;
var
  TI: PTypeInfo;
begin
  Result := nil;

  TI := TypeInfo(SetType);
  if not (Assigned(TI) and (TI^.Kind = tkSet)) then Exit;

  TD := GetTypeData(TI);
  if not (Assigned(TD^.CompType) and (TD^.CompType^ = TypInfo(EnumType)) and (TD^.CompType^.Kind = tkEnumeration)) then Exit;

  Result := GetTypeData(TD^.CompType^);
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<EnumType, SetType>.LoadEnums(const ASet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  AList.CheckAll(cbUnchecked);

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if EnumType(Value) in ASet then
      AList.Checked[Value] := True;
  end;
end;

class procedure TEnumSerialize<SetType>.SaveEnums(var VSet: SetType; AList: TCheckListBox);
var
  TD: PTypeData;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  VSet := [];

  TD := GetEnumTypeData;
  if not Assigned(TD) then Exit;

  for Value := TD^.MinValue to TD^.MaxValue do
  begin
    if AList.Checked[Value] then
      Include(VSet, EnumType(Value));
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
type
  TMyEnum = (meOne, meTwo, meThree);
  TMyEnums = set of TMyEnum;

var
  MyEnums: TMyEnums;

// initialize MyEnums as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnum, TMyEnums>.LoadEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// use lstMyEnumCheckList as needed...
TEnumSerialize<TMyEnum, TMyEnums>.SaveEnums(MyEnums, lstMyEnumCheckList);
// save MyEnums as needed...
```

Comment: Most excellent. Before I go and try to implement it, I'm just guessing / assuming that there may be a way to possibly pass only the set, and have it automatically determine the enum type, without having to pass both?

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.  I think there is a way, let me check...

Comment: `type SetType = Set of EnumType;` - E2001 Ordinal type required

Comment: In the alternative... `if Value in ASet then` - E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: `E2001 Ordinal type required` ... `E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type` - I was afraid of that. I don't have a compiler installed right now to verify the syntax, you will just have to play with it. You might not be able to get away with not specifying both types in the Generic parameters.

Comment: And now it's time to play... "If Remy can't figure it out, who can?" :-) Thanks for your effort, surely these hurdles can be jumped sooner or later.

Comment: Stefan Glienke can maybe ;-)