# How to convert set of integer to comma separated string in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

```
  private const
    CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS = [1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13];
```

I can use the "for" loop, but how can I use some generics to get a comma separated string like '1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13' without any loops?

Comment: This may come as a surprise to you, but `CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS` is NOT an array at all. It is a *set*. Maybe you mean `private const CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS: array[0..5] of Integer = (1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13);`?

Comment: Yes of course you are right :) But it's not so easy to convert a set to a string without a loop through all the elements and checking for an occurrence.

Comment: I need to use "in" operator like a "if x in CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS".

Comment: Just beware that the base type of a Delphi set can be no larger than a byte. For instance, `[1, 5, 6, 9, 311, 13]` won't compile. You could use an array of integers instead and check for "contains" using a loop (or binary search or whatever). Using operator overloading, you can even construct a record type containing such an array and having an overloaded `in` operator to make things like`a in X` work.

Comment: If you use an array instead of a Set, then Delphi has a [`TStringHelper.Join()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Join) method that creates a delimited string from an array of values. If you absolutely must use a Set, then you could write a custom class that wraps the Set inside an implementation of `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerable`, and then use that enum with `Join()`. Otherwise, just use your own loop, it is really not hard to write.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no solution using generics for looping through a set, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685038/how-to-traverse-the-enums-in-any-given-set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way uses the TStringList class from the System.Classes unit:

```
const
  CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS = [1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13];
var
  c: integer;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for c in CA_2_4_RECOMMENDED_CHANNELS do
      sl.Add(c.ToString);
    writeln(sl.CommaText);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But even with this solution, a For-Each loop is required to fill the StringList. A solution where each element must not be touched does not exist from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RTTI, for example.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Rtti;




type
  TMySet=set of byte;
var
  m: TMySet;
  v: TValue;
begin
  try
    m := [1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13];
    v := TValue.From<TMySet>(m);
    writeln(v.ToString());
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```